# Is it possible to modify the value of an input parameter from within the same function to which it was passed?

Tags: sql-server, function, parameters, local-variables

Currently I am having to assign the value of the parameter to a local variable.  I am obviously able to modify that.

Just wanted to trim down the code a bit and lessen the confusion when it comes to parameters and local variables that start with the same values.

i.e.

*@parameterAddress*   vs.  *@variableAddress*

Being able to work with *@parameterAddress* alone would be much simpler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You asked about a function, rather than a stored procedure, so the answer should be yes. However you are right to be cautious.

A simple test shows that the variable being passed to the function doesn't get changed. This indicates that the parameter is being passed by value (ie a copy is passed on the stack), and not by reference.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.MyFunc
(
    @input int
)
RETURNS int
BEGIN
    SET @input = @input + 3;
    RETURN @input;
END;

DECLARE @i INT;
SET @i = 2;

SELECT dbo.MyFunc(@i);

SELECT @i as '@i';
```

The results are 5 and 2. So @i doesn't get changed, even though @input has been changed inside the function.

Comment: I took the word "function" in a general since, not a "user defined function" sense......so good observation.

Comment: I meant in this case user T-V functions.  In scripting environments, it's easy to get lazy and not clearly label variables - thereby treating all variables alike.

Answer (score 0):

If you are speaking of a stored procedure......then here is a response.

(I'm not sure by "function" you mean that in a general sense...or specifically a "user defined function".)

HOWEVER:
Creating a local variable and setting it to a the value of an input-parameter is a WELL KNOWN SQL-PARAMETER-SNIFFING workaround.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/turgays/archive/2013/09/10/parameter-sniffing-problem-and-workarounds.aspx

look for "Use Local Variables" in the above link.

So your efforts to make the code "trimmer" may have unintended consequences.

Just run this part over and over and see what happens:

```
Declare @OrderID int
select @OrderID = -99999
EXEC dbo.uspOrderGetByOverrideSurrogateKey @OrderID
```

Full code:

```
Use Northwind
GO

/*

Declare @OrderID int
select @OrderID = -99999
EXEC dbo.uspOrderGetByOverrideSurrogateKey @OrderID

*/


IF EXISTS 
    (
    SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES  WHERE ROUTINE_TYPE = N'PROCEDURE' and ROUTINE_SCHEMA = N'dbo' and ROUTINE_NAME = N'uspOrderGetByOverrideSurrogateKey'  
    )
BEGIN
    DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].[uspOrderGetByOverrideSurrogateKey]
END


GO

CREATE Procedure dbo.uspOrderGetByOverrideSurrogateKey (
@OrderID int
)
AS

BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON

    Select @OrderID = (select top 1 OrderID from dbo.Orders order by newid() )


    SELECT o.OrderID,o.CustomerID,o.EmployeeID,o.OrderDate,o.RequiredDate,o.ShippedDate,o.ShipVia ,o.Freight,o.ShipName,o.ShipAddress,o.OrderID,o.CustomerID,o.EmployeeID,o.OrderDate 
    FROM 
        dbo.Orders o 
     WHERE 
        o.OrderID = @OrderID


    SET NOCOUNT OFF

END

GO
```